# sugar CRM 6.1 .how do i edit Detailview of account module

Tags: sugarcrm

I am working on customizing sugar CRM 6.1 . I am editing Detailview of account module,
In detailview I am adding a custom array stored in this variable

```
 $this->bean->extra_phonenumbers = array( "phone1" =>'434343' , "phone2"=>'32323223' , "phone3"=>'344343545679');
```

Can anybody help me how to display these array systematically in Default viewdetail.php of Account module.

You can see view.details.php in account module `<baseurl>/modules/Accounts/views/view.details.php`

Answer (score 0):

Declare this field in `vardefs.php` for `Accounts` and then add it to `metadata/detailviewdefs.php`. You can use `customCode` property for non-standard displays - see how it's done for existing fields there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing Detailview "View" class then you can assign that field to a smarty variable $this->ss->assign and add in detailviewdefs to show that field with customCode as suggested above if needed.